# Cannot connect to MSSQL database from android

Tags: android, sql-server

This is the code of my Connection Class, but the connection is not getting established. Whenever I print con I get null , Can anyone tell me where I went wrong? I included the jtds-1.3.1.jar in lib folder of app. I am unable to understand where I went wrong

```
package com.jazzitup.music;



import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

import java.sql.*;
import net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.*;
public class   ConnectionClass {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static Connection CONN() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL = null;
        try {

            //Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://jazzitup.database.windows.net:1433;database=jazzitup.db;user=xxxxxxxx;password=xxxxxx;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;");
            System.out.println("CON:"+conn);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's preferable (or a must i think)  to use web services to access your data base from the device and not using a direct connection . Not every lib for java works with andoid .

Answer (score 0):

1.First of all make class that `extend SQLiteOpenHelper`

2.Create a contractor for that class and implement all the function that needed .

3. On the method

> onCreate((SQLiteDatabasedb)

Just create String called query
and create the table you want , and execSql it , for example :

> ```
> String query="create table if not exists table(text text,name text2,_id text)";
> db.execSQL(query);
> ```

Then for create new row in the sql lite use :

> ```
>  public void add_new_row(String text,String text2,String _id){
> try{
> ContentValues cn=new ContentValues(); 
> cn.put("text",per_name); 
> cn.put("text2",per_age);      
> cn.put("_id",per_age);      
>
> SQLiteDatabase db;     
> db=getWritableDatabase();   
> db.insert("table",null,cn);}
> catch(Exception e){
> Log.i("AddSql_lite","Print :"+e.to );
>
> }
> ```

And for read Row from sqllite you just use :

> public String getRow_by_id(String _id){
>           string text = "";
>           try{
>               db=getWritableDatabase();
>                       query="select * from table where _id = '"+_id+"'";
>
> ```
>         Cursor cr=db.rawQuery(query, null);
>         if(cr.moveToFirst()){
>             do{
>                 text = cr.getString(0);
>                 String text2 = cr.getString(1);
>                 String _id = cr.getString(2);
>             }while(cr.moveToNext());
>         }
>
>     }catch(Exception e){
>     }
>
>     return text;
> }
> ```

And for reading all the rows in the table one after another :

> public int get_all_Rows(){
>           string int counter = 0;
>           try{
>               db=getWritableDatabase();
>                       query="select * from table";
>
> ```
>         Cursor cr=db.rawQuery(query, null);
>         if(cr.moveToFirst()){
>             do{
>                 text = cr.getString(0);
>                 String text2 = cr.getString(1);
>                 String _id = cr.getString(2);
>                 counter++;
>             }while(cr.moveToNext());
>         }
>
>     }catch(Exception e){
>     }
>
>     return counter;
> }
> ```

Hope its will help you to understand how Sqllite work and how build it correctly :)

And for make it run so just :

> SQLiteDataBase Sqllite_ref = new SQLiteDataBase(context, "VerName",
>   null, 1);
>
> Sqllite_ref.add_new_row("hey","hey4","1");
>   Sqllite_ref.add_new_row("hey2","hey5","2");
>   Sqllite_ref.add_new_row("hey3","hey6","3");
>
> Sqllite_ref.getRow_by_id("2");>>> will return "hey2"
>   Sqllite_ref.get_all_Rows()>>> will return 3 [number of items you have
>   in the sqllite]